# Comparing last modified date of a file and current date in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to create a new file if the last modified date of the previously created file is less then the current date. Below is the code i tried but not sure getting what value as difference between last modified date and current date.

Code

```
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE=$(stat -c %y ${APPDIR}/data/XYZ.csv)
    echo "LAST_MODIFIED_DATE ${LAST_MODIFIED_DATE}"
    NOW=$(date +%s)
    echo "NOW ${NOW}"
    let diff=${NOW}-${LAST_MODIFIED_DATE}
    echo "Diff ${diff}"
```

Result

```
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE 2021-08-03 10:30:56.627022878 -0500
NOW 1629354883
Diff 1629354883-2021-08-03 10:30:56.627022878 -0500
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE` in seconds since 1970-01-01 first:

```
NOW="$(date +%s)"
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE="$(stat -c %y ${APPDIR}/data/XYZ.csv)"
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_EPOCH="$(date +%s --date="$LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")"

diff=$(($NOW - $LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_EPOCH))
echo "Diff ${diff}"
```

But `diff` will be all the time positive unless the file `${APPDIR}/data/XYZ.csv` was created with a date in the future.

If you want to test against a different date (for instance to check whether the file has been created in the last hour or not) you can modify the definition of `NOW`:

```
NOW="$(date +%s --date '1 hour ago')"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I used %d, %m and %y in order to get the values of last modified file and now and then compared them individually and that worked.